# Slazzer API integration

Tags: javascript, api

I am trying to integrate https://slazzer.com/api.
Here is the code I am using. But it is giving the error : "Source image  not found"

```
var imgData = {
source_image_url: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1598864855111-bfa107cc62a3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=80", 
  crop: true
}
var post = $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://slazzer.com/api/v1/remove_image_background',
    headers: {
        'API-KEY': '<api key here>',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
        data: imgData
});
post.success(function (data, status) {
    if (data.success) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
post.error(function (data, status) {                       
        console.log(data);                      
});
```

Comment: You need to debug the image url `https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1598864855111-bfa107cc62a3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=80` - the mimetype of that image is `image/webp` so it's a WEBP file and the API source image url support only PNG, JPG, JPEG.

Comment: I got a comment from Slazzer .com <support@slazzer.com>
Thu, Aug 6, 2020 10:46 PM
We have already fixed this and we will giving an update soon. 
Along with this we will be adding a few more updates including support for API previews and support for tiff , WEBP formats as well. After all Postman is giving the result {"output_image_url":
"https://www.slazzer.com/downloads/69286213-f5ea-11ea-bbfc-0200a434c31d/photo-1598864855111-bfa107cc62a3.png"}